# Reuse usercontrol in mail in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls

After a user purchases a product, a receipt is displayed.

I need to also email this receipt to the customer (as html), and would like to reuse the view I already created.

What is the best way to do that - and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this would do the trick:
[Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)